# How do i fire an event in model when user is created in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a controller that's called EventtypeController, it has an store function and i want to fire this event whenever an user is created. I tried reading the events page on the laravel doc but no luck yet.

How do i fire that eventtype create function in the user model whenever a user is created?

this is what i tried:

```
public function boot()
{
    User::creating(function($model) {
        var_dump($model->name);
    });
}
```

it says: "Method 'App\Models\User::boot()' is not compatible with method 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User::boot()'."

Comment: Please take a look at how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask add the code you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) like

```php
class UserObserver
{
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        // do something when a user is created
    }
}

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track if you didn't want to go through the work of building an observer. But you're code is a little off. `booting` should be `booted`, for example.

This should work for your example:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::created(function($model) {
        var_dump($model->name);
    });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).